# Evaluating Boolean logic with 3 or more variables

Tags: python-3.x, boolean, boolean-expression

I'm trying to understand the behaviour of Python when I am evaluating three Boolean variables.

```py
>>> True and True and False == False
True
```

Evaluates to **'True'** which is what I would expect.

However

```py
>>> True and False and True == False
False
>>> False and True and True == False
False
```

both evaluate to **'False'** when I expected **True**. Can someone help me understand what I'm missing here. I've tried searching but I can't find examples where 3 Boolean variables are evaluated in a single statement.

Thanks!

[image: Python Boolean statements]

Answer (score 0):

This is the explanation I can think of

```
False and True and True == False
False and True and False        ( because True == False results in False)
(False and True) and False
False and False                 ( because 0 and 1 is 0)
False                           ( because 0 and 0 is 0)


True and False and True == False
True and False and False        ( because True == False results in False)
(True and False) and False      
False and False                 ( because 0 and 1 is 0)
False                           ( because 0 and 0 is 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Its assume like three input And Gate table

```
A   B   C   output
0   0   0   0
0   0   1   0
0   1   0   0
0   1   1   0
1   0   0   0
1   0   1   0
1   1   0   0
1   1   1   1


True and True and False == False  # 0 and 0 and 0 the answer is 0 (False)
False and True and True == False  # 0 and 1 and 0 the answer is 0 (False)
False and True and True == False  # 0 and 1 and 0 the answer is 0 (False)
```

if you would like to understand more variables

```
True and True and True and True and False  
 # 1 and 1 and 1 and 1 and 0  output will be 0 (False)
 # 1 * 1 * 1 * 1 * 0 output will be 0 (False)

True and True and True and True and True 
 # 1 and 1 and 1 and 1 and 1  output will be 1 (True)
 # 1 * 1 * 1 * 1 * 1 output will be 1 (True)

True and False or True or True or True 
# 1 and 1 or 1 or 1 or 1  output will be 1 (True)
# 1 * 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 output will be 1 (True)
```

Comment: Ananth, what you describe is the behavior I would expect.

However if you enter "False and True and True == False" into the python console it will evaluate to "False".

Comment: I've updated my original post with a screenshot of the behaviour

Comment: @ilmatic9000 Ofcourse it False,Can you please let me know what you couldn't understand?

Answer (score -1):

Ok I've worked it out.

The '==' operator is taking precedence and is being evaluated first.

If I enclose the statement to the left in brackets then I get the expected behavior specified in the response posted by https://stackoverflow.com/users/10384101/ananth-p

**With Brackets**

```py
Python 3.7.4 (default, Aug 13 2019, 15:17:50) 
[Clang 4.0.1 (tags/RELEASE_401/final)] :: Anaconda, Inc. on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

>>> (True and True and False) == False
True
>>> (True and False and True) == False
True
>>> (False and True and True) == False
True
```

**Without brackets**

```py
>>> True and True and False == False
True
>>> True and False and True == False
False
>>> False and True and True == False
False
>>>
```

Comment: Exactly,did I help you ?

Comment: The issue was that I didn't enclose the statement on the left in brackets. Python evaluated the '==' before evaluating the 'and' which was causing the behavior observed in my initial post.

So yes you were helpful in confirming my understanding of Boolean operations. 

e.g. The following two statements are identical apart from the brackets on the LHS. The first evaluates to 'False' and the second to 'True'.

>>> False and True and True == False
False
>>> (False and True and True) == False
True

Comment: Yes Precedence and brackets played a role here

Comment: "The '==' operator is taking precedence and is being evaluated first" no, `==` is evaluated last and lazily. What you're missing is that the boolean operators are "at the top" (because you usually want e.g. `a == b and c == d` to be `(a == b) and (c == d)` not `a == (b and c) == d`), so `True and False and True == False` is parsed as `(True) and (False) and (True == False)`, which is obviously `False` `x and False and x` is necessarily False.

Comment: Masklinn - So the statement **"True and True and False == False"**  is being broken up into **1.)"True and True"**,  **2.) "False == False"**. **1.), 2.)** are evaluated first, then the results of **1.), 2.)** are evaluated as **"1.) and 2.)"** returning **'True'**?

Comment: @ilmatic9000 this is exactly what I have explained in my answer - with the precedence